# Exponential inequality solution

Tags: exponential-function

I am trying to solve 
$$  \displaystyle (2^{(3x-1)/(x-1)})^{1/3} < 8^{((x-3)/(3x-7))}$$

Here's how I proceeded.

$LHS = 2^{((3x-1)/(3(x-1))}  , RHS = 2^{((3*(x-3))/(3x-7))}$

hence inequating the exponents ,

$$\frac {(3x-1)}{(3(x-1))} < 3\frac {(x-3)}{(3x-7)}$$

$$ \implies  (3x-1)(3x-7) < 9(x-1)(x-3)$$

$$\implies    9x^2-24x+7 < 9x^2-36x+27$$

cancelling terms

$$12x <20$$

$$=> x < 5/3 $$

but the book states the solution as $(-\infty , 1)$ U $(5/3,7/3)$

Not sure how this has been arrived at , can someone help me understand ?

Thanks in advance.

Madavan.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: When you multiply an inequality you have to care about the sign of the factor... there are many cases...negatif or positif...

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull when you multiply your inequality
$$\frac {(3x-1)}{(3(x-1))} < 3\frac {(x-3)}{(3x-7)}$$
Because $3x-7$ or $3(x-1)$ may be negative and change the order of the ineqaulity

You need to study the sign of $3(x-1)(3x-7)$...

**A)$ \,3(x-1)(3x-7) $ is positive**

$$\implies  (3x-1)(3x-7) < 9(x-1)(x-3)$$
$$ \implies x<5/3$$

***First case*** $3(x-1)>0$ and $3x-7>0 \implies x> \frac 73$
With the constraint $x>7/3$ there are no solution.

***Second case*** $3(x-1)<0$ and $3x-7<0$

$$\implies x<1$$

with this constraint ($x<1$) you get a part of the result of the book $ \implies x \in [-\infty,1]$.

Now you have to study the case when $3(x-1)(3x-7)$ is negative to get the other part of the solution of the book...

**B)$ \,3(x-1)(3x-7) $ is negative**

$$  (3x-1)(3x-7) > 9(x-1)(x-3)$$
$$ \implies  x>\frac 5 3$$

***First case***
$3(x-1)<0 \quad ; 3x-7>0 \implies x<1, x>7/3$ Impossible ..

***Second case***
$3(x-1)>0 \quad ; 3x-7<0 \implies x>1, x<7/3$ .

With the constraint you finally get $x \in (5/3,7/3)$

And the complete solution is $(-\infty,1)$ U $(5/3,7/3)$

Comment: Sorry i dont understand the reply fully , from where  does the 5/3 come in to picture ? Can you please explain in more detail ? Thanks.

Comment: First consider that both polynomials are positive you get a constraint on the variable x ...When you solved the inequality you get some values for x...you check that both the solution and the constraint match  @Madavan

Comment: @Madavan whern you multiply an inequality by a positive number it stay the same. For example multily by 3 $$x>3 \implies 3x>9$$ But when the number is negative it changes the inequality. Example multiply by -3 $$x>3 \implies -3x<-9$$

Comment: Got it , thanks very much Isham.

Comment: yw @Madavan ...